# Do the Simpsons have to pay copyright?

Tags: the-simpsons, copyright

I can recall an episode of *The Simpsons* in which Bart and the bullies go to a *bully meeting*. In this meeting one that seems to be the boss starts a speach but is interrupted by another bully who hits him with a sling and then accuses Bart. The bully have now to go back to Springfield traversig the territory of other bullies.

This is the plot of the movie ***[The warriors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Warriors_(film))***.

I recall this episode now, but there are many other examples, so I wonder: do the creators of the Simpsons have to pay copyright to the film maker for *copying* the plot of the movie?

Comment: "It is based on Sol Yurick's 1965 novel of the same name, which was, in turn, based on Xenophon's Anabasis." wonder how much fees went to Xenophon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This kind of thing is common to *The Simpsons* and a lot of shows, and falls under [fair use as parody](https://copyrightalliance.org/ca_faq_post/parody-considered-fair-use-satire-isnt/) - so it is highly unlikely that any royalty or licence fee would have to be paid in this instance.